# Find the first proc that doesn't raise an error, and get its return value

Tags: ruby

The scenario is something like this: you have some input you want to process using one of several possible procs, depending on some quality of the input itself. You don't know ahead of time which is going to work, until you try sending the input to each.

Let's say you have an array of possible procs to try. What you want is to *find the first proc that doesn't raise an error, and get its return value*, preferably in one pass. And if no proc is found, raise an error.

How would you best do this in ruby?

My answer so far looks like one of the two below, but I am looking for a more idiomatic way. And also a way that treats a return value of nil as valid -- right now both of these treat nil as the error state.

(1)

```
ret = nil
array_of_procs.find do |p|
   begin
     ret = p[input]
   rescue
     next
   end
end
raise ArgumentError unless ret
```

(2)

```
ret = array_of_procs.inject(nil) do |memo, p|
  memo = p[input] rescue next
  break memo
end
raise ArgumentError unless ret
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution, note that the rescue modifier rescues StandardError and I don't think there is any way to change that without going to multi-line block.

```
def first_valid_result(procs, input)
  procs.each { |p| return p[input] rescue nil }
  raise ArgumentError
end
```

And here's the spec

```
describe '#first_valid_result' do
  let(:error_proc)  { lambda { |input| raise } }
  let(:procs)       { [error_proc] * 2 }
  let(:input)       { :some_input }

  it "returns the input from the first proc that doesnt raise an error" do
    procs.insert 1, lambda { |input| input }
    first_valid_result(procs, input).should == input
  end

  it "treats nil as a valid return value" do
    procs.insert 1, lambda { |input| nil }
    first_valid_result(procs, input).should be_nil
  end

  it "raises an ArgumentError when no valid proc exists" do
    expect { first_valid_result procs, input }.to raise_error ArgumentError
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, putting it in its own method so you can use an explicit return makes a lot of sense, and is easier to understand all around.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your code to this:

```
array_of_procs.find {|p| ret=p[input] rescue StandardError next}; raise ArgumentError("...") unless ret
```

I think...

Answer (score 0):

Adapting Joshua's answer a little bit so it can be called on the array itself, and allowing 'fail' behavior to be injected in:

```
module ArrayofProcsMethods
  def find_call(*args)
    self.each { |p| return p[*args] rescue nil }
    block_given? ? yield : raise(ArgumentError, "No valid proc found")
  end
end

array_of_procs.extend(ArrayofProcsMethods)
array_of_procs.find_call(input) 
array_of_procs.find_call(input) { default_value }
array_of_procs.find_call(input) { raise ProcNotFoundCustomError }
```